# What kind of wine is a funeral wine?

Tags: neil-gaiman, food, anansi-boys

I've been re-reading *Anansi Boys* and I came upon something that piqued my interest. It was a wine that Spider and Fat Charlie were drinking in honour of their dad passing. Spider called it a funeral wine.

> Spider poured from the bottle a wine so tawny it was almost black. He filled each glass, then put one in front of Fat Charlie.
>
> "A toast," he said. "To our father's memory."
>
> "To Dad," said Fat Charlie, and he clinked his glass against Spider's - managing, miraculously, not to spill any as he did so - and he tasted his wine. It was peculiarly bitter and herby, and salt. "What is this?"
>
> "Funeral wine, the kind you drink for gods. They haven't made it for a long time. It's seasoned with bitter aloes and rosemary, and with the tears of brokenhearted virgins."

When the wine was poured from a bottle it was *so tawny it was almost black* hence the thought of it to be a particularly dark red wine.
This really tells me nothing since I'm not a wine connoisseur and I'm not a big fan of a red wine, but if some one could point me to a direction of what would be a closest real red wine to this description I would really appreciate it. Pointing out why some one would think it is not a real wine and just a figment of Gaiman's imagination would be acceptable as well.

Comment: Australian Shiraz vines are said to produce wine that noticeably contains salt. There is Rosemary wine, and aloe wine. If you're looking for something that may be similar, try getting a South East Australian Blend. http://www.snooth.com/region/south-east-australia/

Comment: It sounds to me like a flight of imagination more than a description of any real wine.  The closest wines I can think of, though, would be [red Vermouth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vermouth) — a herbal, often bitter, slightly sweet fortified wine.  Dolin is my personal favourite brand (though I prefer their white to their red).

Comment: "Wine. Is. Red."

Answer (score 2):

In traditional West African cultures (where the stories of Anansi come from), ceremonial wine is made from palm trees.  However, it is, as far as I can tell, white.